# Material Angular scroll to element on mat-list

Tags: angular, scroll, angular-material, material-design

I have an Angular Material list with multiple elements, where one of them can be selected.

When I load this list I want to scroll list up to that selected element, to make it more visible. Is there any option?

I was thinking about something like in ngOnInit to check if item is selected, but I have really no idea how to scroll this list up to that item.

Note: not whole page should be scrolled, only the elements on the list.

component.html

```html
    <mat-nav-list>
        <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemClick(item)"
            [ngClass]="item.selectedClass">
            {{item.someValue}}
        </mat-list-item>
    </mat-nav-list>
```

component.ts

```js
    private itemClick(item: Item): Observable<any> {
        if (item) {
            this.something = item;
            this.items.forEach(item => {
                if (item && item.name === item.name) {
                    item["selectedClass"] = "item-selected";
                } else {
                    item["selectedClass"] = undefined;
                }
            });
        } else {
            this.something = null;
            this.items.forEach(item => {
                    item["selectedClass"] = undefined;
            });
        }

        return of(null);
    }
```

Comment: can you post your current code so we can see what you're working with?

Comment: Posted simplified, hope didn't make any mistakes during it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out this demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yjbpoq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

The gist is that you attach a new directive to your list and to each of your list items:

```
<mat-list appScrollable ...>
  <mat-list-item appOffsetTop ...>
  ...
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

The one on the list can set the `scrollTop` (or use `scrollTo`, or whatever) for the list:

```
@Directive({selector: '[appScrollable]'})
export class ScrollableDirective {
  constructor(private _el: ElementRef) {}
  set scrollTop(value: number) { this._el.nativeElement.scrollTop = value; }
}
```

And the one on the list items can report their `offsetTop`s:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[appOffsetTop]'})
export class OffsetTopDirective {
  constructor(private _el: ElementRef) { }
  get offsetTop(): number { return this._el.nativeElement.offsetTop; }
}
```

Each type of directive is accessed in the component via `@ViewChild` and `@ViewChildren`:

```
  @ViewChildren(OffsetTopDirective) listItems: QueryList<OffsetTopDirective>;
  @ViewChild(ScrollableDirective) list: ScrollableDirective;
```

In the `AfterViewInit` life cycle hook, the list of items is searched for the one that matches the current selected item (set randomly here for illustration purposes).  The list's `scrollTop` is then set to that item's `offsetTop`:

```
  // Inside your component
  selectedItem = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
  items = new Array(500).fill(0).map((_, i) => `Item ${i}`);

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.list.scrollTop = this.listItems.find((_, i) => i === this.selectedItem).offsetTop;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks really nice, but I don't know why, when I'm trying to call this.list I'm getting undefined.

this.list.scrollTo = this.listItems.find((_, i) => this.targets[i]["isSelected"] === "selected").offsetTo;

I tried also to use #list and #listItems together with selector, but also without any change.

Comment: Two things come to mind: have you created the two directives, as I have in the Stackblitz?  And are you using AfterViewInit rather than OnInit (view children references aren't guaranteed until the AfterViewInit lifecycle hook)?

Comment: Yes, I have both directives, also used in ngAfterViewInit and also tried in other place, where I'm sure that data is loaded there ;)


listItems also are empty :/

Comment: Then tbh I'm not really sure what may be wrong, without seeing your code directly :/

Comment: Okay, stupid me, seems I've forgot 'bout modules... Anyway, thanks! ;)

Comment: Thank's it works, for me but I need to call setting command after getting data in setTimeout:

`
setTimeout(() => {
        
        this.list.scrollTop = this.listItems.find((_, i) => i === 23).offsetTop;
      }, 0);
`

Comment: @OldShaterhan I have the same issue, what modules you added to make it work ?

Comment: @armadillo.mx I'm not sure how actual your question is, but, tbh I don't remember - some time ago, it's not used by me no more now.

Comment: In response to those who get zero `listItems` and are wondering about the modules comment above; make sure the new directives are included in the `declarations` of `app.module.ts`

Answer (score 6):

You can use the directive approach with **scrollIntoView**:

```typescript
@Directive({
  selector: '[appScrollIntoView]'
})
export class ScrollIntoViewDirective implements OnChanges {
  @Input() appScrollIntoView: boolean | undefined;

  constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: any,
    private elementRef: ElementRef
  ) {}

  ngOnChanges(simpleChange: SimpleChanges) {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      if (coerceBooleanProperty(this.appScrollIntoView)) {
        (this.elementRef.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement).scrollIntoView({
          behavior: 'smooth',
          block: 'center'
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

usage:

```html
  <mat-list class="list" role="list">
    <mat-list-item
      class="list-item"
      [class.selected]="item === selectedItem"
      [appScrollIntoView]="item === selectedItem"
      *ngFor="let item of items"
      (click)="selectedItem = item"
      role="listitem"
      >{{ item.name }}</mat-list-item
    >
  </mat-list>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/scroll-into-view-demo?file=src/app/app.component.html)

If you use the material selection list the [MatListOption](https://stackblitz.com/edit/scroll-into-view-demo?file=src/app/app.component.html) has a **focus** method which is another option.

```typescript
@Directive({
  selector: 'mat-list-option[appScrollIntoView]'
})
export class ScrollIntoViewDirective implements OnChanges {
  @Input() appScrollIntoView: boolean | undefined;

  constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: any,
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private matListOption: MatListOption
  ) {}

  ngOnChanges(simpleChange: SimpleChanges) {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      if (coerceBooleanProperty(this.appScrollIntoView)) {
        this.matListOption.focus();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

usage:

```html
  <mat-selection-list
    (selectionChange)="selectedItem = $event.option.value"
    class="list"
    [multiple]="false"
    role="list"
    #itemList
  >
    <mat-list-option
      class="list-item"
      [appScrollIntoView]="option.selected"
      *ngFor="let item of items"
      role="listitem"
      [selected]="item === selectedItem"
      [value]="item"
      #option
      >{{ item.name }}</mat-list-option
    >
  </mat-selection-list>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/scroll-into-view-demo-select-list?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hard without code, but you can give all your elements an ID, maybe like

Then with`ngOnInit` you can check for your selected element, select the DOM element with `document.getElementById('listelement'+elementid)` and scroll it into view.
Classic JS way to do this would be `element.scrollIntoView();`

Comment: I updated question with simplified code.

Question: does it will scroll whole window, or only elements inside box?

Comment: Per default it should scroll the entire window. You can use this instead to just scroll the container: `var target = document.getElementById("target");
target.parentNode.scrollTop = target.offsetTop;` target is your element in this case