# Focus a specific mat-option item when mat-select dialog is opened?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, select-options

I want to focus to an option(scroll to an option) automatically when mat-select is opened. I thought that with a little bit of search this will be solved easily but I couldn't found a solid answer anywhere.

Here is the mat-select that I use.

```
             <mat-select required name="AngabeId" [(ngModel)]="bedingungszielList[0]?.BedingungenList[i].AngabeId">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let antragsbereich of antragsBereichListWithAngabelist">
                  <mat-optgroup *ngIf="antragsbereich.AngabeList.length > 0" [label]="antragsbereich.Bezeichnung" class="bedigungOptGroup">
                    <ng-container *ngFor="let angabe of antragsbereich.AngabeList">
                      <mat-option *ngIf="angabe.Id !== Id" [value]="angabe.Id" class="bedigungOptions">
                        {{ angabe.Fragetext }}
                      </mat-option>
                    </ng-container>
                  </mat-optgroup>
                </ng-container>
              </mat-select>
```

And here is some sample code of what I whant to achieve, angabe.Id being the mat-option ngmodel.

```
  this.antragsBereichListWithAngabelist.forEach(element => {
    element.AngabeList.forEach(angabe => {
       if(angabe.Id===962)
         angabe.Id.focus(); // mat-option focus, my intention, sample code(bad)
    });
  });
```

Here's the example with image:
[mat-option focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZzHm.png)

Comment: Try `<mat-select ... [(value)]="yourFunction()" ...>`

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you wanted to focus a option when you open select box. So, I would suggest you to use (opened) event in mat-select. This is something I tried:

.html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Cars</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="default" required (opened)="selectOpened()">
    <mat-option value="volvo">Volvo</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="saab">Saab</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="mercedes">Mercedes</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="audi">Audi</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

.ts

```
default = '';

selectOpened() {
    this.default = 'audi';
}
```

This code will focus audi option when select box is opened. Hope this is useful for you.

Comment: Thank you, the thing is that, I don't need a value I want just the focus, something like this is fine

document.querySelectorAll('.bedigungOptGroup').forEach(item=>{
             if(item.getAttribute("antragsId")===this.antragsBereichValueSelected.toString()) 
                item.scrollIntoView();
          });

Comment: You don't need value? How can you focus option without value? Even, in the snipped you provided, you are using value.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that might have the same problem, combined with Maruthi Eranki answer this is what I came up with..

```
  selectOpened() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.bedigungOptGroup').forEach(item=>{
  if(item.getAttribute("antragsId") === 
  this.antragsBereichValueSelected.toString()) 
     item.scrollIntoView(true);
  });
}
```

Comment: Though I'm not crazy about using `scrollIntoView` you may find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54310902/material-angular-scroll-to-element-on-mat-list

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is get that mat-option element and then use the scrollIntoview funtion, please check [this docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).